# Object permission settings not enabled for community profile

Tags: custom-object, permissions

I am not able to view the custom object permissions enabled for Customer Community profile. What could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: Hi For all the Standard profiles which were given by salesforce you cannot edit the access for custom objects. For that you need to clone the profile and give the required permission for the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the Standard profiles which were given by salesforce you cannot edit the access for custom objects. You can only update object permission for custom profiles only.

Customer Community is standard profile that meant to be just assign to user. If you need to change permission of this profile, then clone it and give extra permission as per your requirement and assign this profile to your users.

Comment: that was helpful thanks @sai